# How do you split a javascript string by spaces and punctuation?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have some random string, for example: `Hello, my name is john.`. I want that string split into an array like this: `Hello, ,,  , my, name, is, john, .,`. I tried `str.split(/[^\w\s]|_/g)`, but it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @davin: capturing parentheses in a regex will splice the captured result into the resulting array, though it does include spaces as well. I can't get a perfectly matching result with just `split` and regexes, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this (I'm not sure if this is what you wanted):

```
str.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, function ($1) { return ' ' + $1 + ' ';}).replace(/[ ]+/g, ' ').split(' ');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zNHJW/3/

Comment: @chromedude The last part could be shortened a little bit to this form: `str.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, function ($1) { return ' ' + $1 + ' ';}).split(/[ ]+/g);`. I'm just not used to using split method with regular expressions.

Answer (score 27):

To split a str on any run of non-word characters I.e. Not A-Z, 0-9, and underscore.

```
var words=str.split(/\W+/);  // assumes str does not begin nor end with whitespace
```

Or, assuming your target language is English, you can extract all *semantically* useful values from a string (i.e. "tokenizing" a string) using:

```
var str='Here\'s a (good, bad, indifferent, ...) '+
        'example sentence to be used in this test '+
        'of English language "token-extraction".',

    punct='\\['+ '\\!'+ '\\"'+ '\\#'+ '\\$'+   // since javascript does not
          '\\%'+ '\\&'+ '\\\''+ '\\('+ '\\)'+  // support POSIX character
          '\\*'+ '\\+'+ '\\,'+ '\\\\'+ '\\-'+  // classes, we'll need our
          '\\.'+ '\\/'+ '\\:'+ '\\;'+ '\\<'+   // own version of [:punct:]
          '\\='+ '\\>'+ '\\?'+ '\\@'+ '\\['+
          '\\]'+ '\\^'+ '\\_'+ '\\`'+ '\\{'+
          '\\|'+ '\\}'+ '\\~'+ '\\]',

    re=new RegExp(     // tokenizer
       '\\s*'+            // discard possible leading whitespace
       '('+               // start capture group
         '\\.{3}'+            // ellipsis (must appear before punct)
       '|'+               // alternator
         '\\w+\\-\\w+'+       // hyphenated words (must appear before punct)
       '|'+               // alternator
         '\\w+\'(?:\\w+)?'+   // compound words (must appear before punct)
       '|'+               // alternator
         '\\w+'+              // other words
       '|'+               // alternator
         '['+punct+']'+        // punct
       ')'                // end capture group
     );

// grep(ary[,filt]) - filters an array
//   note: could use jQuery.grep() instead
// @param {Array}    ary    array of members to filter
// @param {Function} filt   function to test truthiness of member,
//   if omitted, "function(member){ if(member) return member; }" is assumed
// @returns {Array}  all members of ary where result of filter is truthy
function grep(ary,filt) {
  var result=[];
  for(var i=0,len=ary.length;i++<len;) {
    var member=ary[i]||'';
    if(filt && (typeof filt === 'Function') ? filt(member) : member) {
      result.push(member);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var tokens=grep( str.split(re) );   // note: filter function omitted 
                                     //       since all we need to test 
                                     //       for is truthiness
```

which produces:

```
tokens=[ 
  'Here\'s',
  'a',
  '(',
  'good',
  ',',
  'bad',
  ',',
  'indifferent',
  ',',
  '...',
  ')',
  'example',
  'sentence',
  'to',
  'be',
  'used',
  'in',
  'this',
  'test',
  'of',
  'English',
  'language',
  '"',
  'token-extraction',
  '"',
  '.'
]
```

EDIT

Also available as a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/1018823)

Comment: `split(/\W+/)` removes all non-English characters. Don't use this for splitting names.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
str.split(/([_\W])/)
```

This will split by any non-alphanumeric character (`\W`) and any underscore. It uses capturing parentheses to include the item that was split by in the final result.

Comment: Since \W means any character that is not A-Z, 0-9, or underscore, you can reduce your /[\W\s_]/ to simply /\W/ to achieve the same effect. To add underscore to your list on unacceptable chars, add it to the beginning of the character class for efficiency.

Comment: @Rob: beat you to it on the `\s` bit. I'll edit it to have the underscore first, though. Thanks.

Comment: The parens are redundant since there is no need to capture anything and should be removed since their addition increases execution time. Also the character class needs to have a plus appended to it (to match one or more) unless you want to have empty results. So, the complete expression should be "str.split(/[\_\W]+/)" (I added the backslash escape to the underscore, even though it's not needed, for readability.)

Comment: @Rob: The parentheses are not redundant. They change the result. I also do not see a backslash in your complete expression.

Comment: of course you're correct. Mea culpa for missing that. One consideration is that using capturing in a regex does increase its execution time so perhaps splitting on all non-targeted values might be a better approach if speed is a concern.

Answer (score 2):

This solution caused a challenge with spaces for me (still needed them), then I gave `str.split(/\b/)` a shot and all is well. Spaces are output in the array, which won't be hard to ignore, and the ones left after punctuation can be trimmed out.