# regular expression for a word

Tags: php, regex

I am doing a string parsing problem in PHP. I want a regular expression for a word in a dictionary. The word can contain only A-Z and a-z. I came up with this regex but this seems to be not working. Can someone help.

```
$regexp = "/[A-z]+/";
if(preg_match($regexp,$buffer)){    
   print $buffer . "<BR>";
}
```

**Adding rkt's comment for eadibility**

currently using this regex

```
$regexp = "/[A-Za-z]+/";
```

but still lot of irrelevant words are getting printed , for eg .

```
a.new,#quickbar a.new{color:#ba0000} enwiki:resourceloader:filter:minify-css:5:f2a9127573a22335c2a9102b208c73e7 wgNamespaceNumber=0;
wgAction="view";
wgPageName="Roger_Federer";
wgMainPageTitle="‌​Main Page";
wgWikimediaMobileUrl="http:\/\/en.m.wikipedia.org\/wiki";
document.writeln("\x3cdiv id=\"localNotice\"\x3e\x3cp\x3e\x3c/p\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e");
```

Comment: Do you mean JUST a word or AT LEAST a word ? What you wrote will match if there is a word, even if there's other stuff as well.

Comment: What, exactly, is not working?

Comment: currently using this regex $regexp = "/[A-Za-z]+/";
but still lot of irrelevant words are getting printed , for eg . a.new,#quickbar
a.new{color:#ba0000} enwiki:resourceloader:filter:minify-css:5:f2a9127573a22335c2a9102b208c73e7
wgNamespaceNumber=0;wgAction="view";wgPageName="Roger_Federer";wgMainPageTitle="Main
Page";wgWikimediaMobileUrl="http:\/\/en.m.wikipedia.org\/wiki";
document.writeln("\x3cdiv
id=\"localNotice\"\x3e\x3cp\x3e\x3c/p\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to match a whole word only...

```
/\b[A-Z]+\b/i
```

Comment: Unless you want to match hyphenated or compound words. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Besides the problem that Limo Wan Kenobi noted, your regex doesn't do what you think it does.

```
/[A-Za-z]+/
```

All this checks is that a letter, either case, appears somewhere in the input. If your input looks like this:

```
1111112222222333333333A333333444444555555567
```

It will still match.

What you are looking for is this regular expression:

```
/^[A-Za-z]+$/
```

This will match the beginning of the string, then one or more letters, and finally the end of the string. Now, there's no room for anything except letters!

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be `/\b[A-Za-z]+\b/`, thought for matching words in a dictionary you probably want something more restrictive than that since words can't usually have caps at any odd location.

Comment: -1 since this won't do what the OP requires. As mentioned above, this regex will match ANY string that contains one or more letters ANYWHERE within the string.

Comment: @Rob. Yeah. If you want to match the full word only then you have to change the regex to /\b[A-Za-z]+\b/

Answer (score 0):

your regex should be

```
$regexp = "/[A-Za-z]+/";
```

Comment: i am still getting some lines in output such as enwiki:resourceloader:filter:minify-css:5:f2a9127573a22335c2a9102b208c73e7
wgNamespaceNumber=0;wgAction="view";wgPageName="Roger_Federer";wgMainPageTitle="Main
Page";wgWikimediaMobileUrl="http:\/\/en.m.wikipedia.org\/wiki";
document.writeln("\x3cdiv
id=\"localNotice\"\x3e\x3cp\x3e\x3c/p\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e");

Comment: i want only alphabets a-z and A-Z in the word

Comment: -1 since this won't do what the OP requires.  As mentioned above, this regex will match ANY string that contains one or more letters ANYWHERE within the string.

Answer (score 0):

You might check my answer to [How do you split a javascript string by spaces and punctuation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162600/how-do-you-split-a-javascript-string-by-spaces-and-punctuation/6162627#comment-7160777) which contains JavaScript which can be used to break English text into an array of words and punctuation, where words can be hyphenated (well-defined) or compound (won't).