# Split a string and separate by punctuation and whitespace

Tags: java, regex, split

I have some strings, for example: `I: am a string, with "punctuation".`
I want to split the string like:

```
["I", ":", "am", "a", "string", ",", "with", "\"", "punctuation", "\"", "."]
```

I tried `text.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+")` but the result is `I, am, a, string, with, punctuation` ...

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162600/how-do-you-split-a-javascript-string-by-spaces-and-punctuation) solution but Java doesn't allow me to split by `\w` .

Comment: Interesting, splitting a string by something, but also keeping that something in the array.

Comment: Keeping something in the array, except for space or tab

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
"\\s+|(?=\\p{Punct})|(?<=\\p{Punct})"
```

The result on your string:

```
["I", ":", "am", "a", "string", ",", "with", "", "\"", "punctuation", "\"", "."]
```

Unfortunately, there is an extra element, the `""` after the with. These extra elements only occur (and always occur) when there is a punctation character after a whitespace character, so this could be fixed by doing `myString.replaceAll("\\s+(?=\\p{Punct})", "").split(regex);` instead of `myString.split(regex);` (ie strip out the whitespace before splitting)

How this works:

- `\\s+` splits on a group of whitespace, so if the characters are whitespace characters, we will remove those characters and split at that location. <sub>*(note: I am assuming that a string of `hello  world` should result in `["hello", "world"]` rather than `["hello", "", "world"]`)*</sub>
- `(?=\\p{Punct})` is a lookahead that splits if the next character is a punctuation character, but it doesn't remove the character.
- `(?<=\\p{Punct})` is a lookbehind that splits if the last character is a punctuation character.

---

EDIT:

In response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222730/split-a-string-and-separate-by-punctuation-and-whitespace/24222825#comment37405688_24222825), this regex should allow punctuation within words:

```
"\\s+|(?=\\W\\p{Punct}|\\p{Punct}\\W)|(?<=\\W\\p{Punct}|\\p{Punct}\\W})"
```

For this one, you don't need to use the `replaceAll`, simply do `myString.split(regex)`.

How it works:

This regex is very similar, but the lookarounds changed. `\\W\\p{Punct}` matches a non-word character followed by a punctuation character. `\\p{Punct}\\W` matches a punctuation character followed by a non-word character. So each lookaround matches iff there is a punctuation character which is not in the middle of a word.

Comment: It print `[I, :, am, a, string, ,, with, , ", punctuation, ", .]` There is an extra space. Look at the empty string.

Comment: @Braj Isn't that exactly what I said? ("Unfortunately, there is an extra element, the `""` after the with.")

Comment: +1. I was thinking of something along these lines, but you beat me to it. Of course, it would be relatively trivial to remove empty spaces from the array (that is to say copy to a new array without the empty string.)

Comment: And what if I want to display the punctuation as single word except for words that does contain the character "-"? For example, the word "I-m" should be left "I-m" , not "I", "-", "m" .

Answer (score 0):

Or try this, collect in an ArrayList:

```
    String s = "I: am a string, with \"punctuation\".";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "\\w+|\\S" );

    Matcher mat = pat.matcher( s );
    while( mat.find() ){
        System.out.print( mat.group() +  "/" );
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Output:

```
 I/:/am/a/string/,/with/"/punctuation/"/./
```