# How to split a string by space and special character in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to split a string by whitespace and special character.

For example:

```
var strSplit = "hell@o wor&ld";
```

I want this output:

```
//["hell","o","wor","ld"]
```

I have tried this method

```
var arr= []; 
"hell@o wor&ld".split(/(\W)/).forEach(function(elem) {
    if (!/^\s*$/.test(elem)) { 
        arr.push(elem);
    }
});
```

I am getting this as the result:

```
// arr= ['hell', '@', 'o', 'wor', '&', 'ld']
```

I am unable to remove the special characters, can anyone help me?

Comment: Remove the capturing from `split`. `.split(/\W/)` is all you need.

Comment: `foo` and `bar` and not in the original string. Where does it come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript regex split produces too many items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516040/javascript-regex-split-produces-too-many-items)

Comment: FWIW, you should use `.filter` to extract the elements that match a predicate from an array, not a `for / push` combo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a javascript string by spaces and punctuation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162600/how-do-you-split-a-javascript-string-by-spaces-and-punctuation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to fix up your regular expression. Instead, use:

`/\W+/`

Here we are splitting by non-word characters (`\W+`) (consecutive)

```js
var strSplit = "hell@o wor&ld";
var splitArr = strSplit.split(/\W+/);

console.log(splitArr);
```

Comment: split is always global.

Comment: Also, if you want consecutive special characters to be ignored, use `/\W+/`, otherwise splitting e.g. `hell@@o` will produce an empty element between the `hell` and the `o`.

Comment: @Alnitak ah, another good pickup, thanks for the feedback, much appreciated :)

Comment: @NickParsons now working for `hell@o wor&ld?`. It gives an empty element at last

Comment: You could add .filter(Boolean) after the .split() call to remove empty strings

Comment: @NickParsons Yes I can do that, But I don't understand why its giving an empty string?

Comment: It gives an empty element because `?` is a non-word character, so it splits whatever’s on the left and right of the question mark into its own elements, since there is an empty string on the right of the `?` you get an empty string

Answer (score 4):

You could split by non word `\W`.

```js
var string = "hell@o wor&ld";

console.log(string.split(/\W+/))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `/\W/`

```js
var strSplit = "hell@o wor&ld";

var arr= "hell@o wor&ld".split(/\W/);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't simply `'hell@o wor&ld'.split(/[ &@]/)` with anything you perceive as a 'special character' within square brackets?